# Tkinter lag at the "update" command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lag

I made a timer just to test something out. and for some reason it starts lagging, here is the timer:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

main = Tk()
main.title("Timer")

c = Canvas(main,width=1000,height=400)
c.pack()
c.config(bg="black")

hours = -1

while True:
    hours += 1
    for minutes in range(60):
        for seconds in range(60):
            c.create_rectangle(0,0,1000,400,fill="black")
            c.create_text(500,200,text=(str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)+":"+str(seconds)),font=("",200),fill="white")
            c.update()
            sleep(1)
```

Can someone figure out where it happens? I noticed I can run the timer without `tkinter` and just with `print`, but I need to use `tkinter` for other projects too.

Comment: It was running fine without any lag for me. But when I close it there were some exceptions at the canvas.create_ rectangle() so try to catch an exception at that time and close the loop.

Comment: @RahulARanger yeah it starts off fine. but i left it running over night and woke up to it being stuck at about 24 mins. if you remove the "sleep(1)" you can see the delay. unless its just computer lagg but i kinda doubt it

Comment: Sleep will freeze the GUI, are you just looking for a way to build a timer?

Comment: @CoolCloud
well yes, the timer was just an easy example so i could get to know how it works. i got an answer tho(below) and were good ;)

Comment: Yes sure, i would also recommend to use `after()`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating text widgets covered by black rectangles in succession, without ever removing them - in essence, every second, you are piling two more canvas items on top of all the previous ones!

The correct approach is to use the `tkinter.mainloop` in conjunction with the `tkinter.after` method, and steer clear from using a while loop, and `tkinter.update`. You can change the text displayed by a canvas text item using `itemconfigure`.

The use of `time.sleep` in a GUI is a recipe to have your GUI stop responding to interactions - don't do that!

Maybe do this instead:

```
import tkinter as tk


def update_clock():
    clock_text = f'{hours}:{str(minutes).zfill(2)}:{str(seconds).zfill(2)}'
    canvas.itemconfigure(clock, text=clock_text)
    main.after(1000, _increment_time)


def _increment_time():
    global clock, hours, minutes, seconds
    seconds += 1
    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes += 1
    if minutes == 60:
        minutes = 0
        hours += 1
    update_clock()
    

main = tk.Tk()
main.title('Timer')

canvas = tk.Canvas(main, width=1000, height=400, bg='black')
canvas.pack()

hours, minutes, seconds = 0, 0, 0
clock = canvas.create_text(500, 200, font=('', 200), fill='white')
update_clock()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I didnt know "canvas.create_text()" actually saved the value. so now i know i just need to use "canvas.delete"

Comment: Im trying to make a snake game while doing this. how do i do that without having to make a variable for each part of the snake?

Comment: Yes, `canvas.create_xxx` returns a reference to the canvas item created; if you keep it, you can use it to modify, or delete the item. One way to code snake is to use a list of positions for the body and head.

Comment: This creates a new text item every second. Why aren't you just reconfiguring the existing text item at every iteration?

Comment: Good idea @BryanOakley, thank you for the suggestion. It allowed me to factor out the updating of the clock, and hide the increment of time from the body of code.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I could make a list of positions for all of the parts of the snake. but won't I need to make a variable for every part? how do I prevent this